# Two ships leave a harbor at the same time.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sounds like a bar joke is about to begin, I have a question on an answer in my homework. I understand the concept of directions/angles. I for some reason stumped on this one question.

Here is the full question:

`Two ships leave a harbor at the same time. One ship travels on a bearing S13°W at 10 miles per hour. The other ship travels on a bearing N75°E at 8 miles per hour. How far apart will the ships be after 22 ​hours?`

I have made a half compass N and S poles. This isn't the prettiest thing in the world but this is kinda how I comprehended it, looks incredibly wrong(enjoy the galaxy paint):

[image: two ships triangle attempt]

Comment: Ships travel in knots, not in miles per hour :-)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Maybe you should tell that to pearson ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

From the above diagram $13^{\circ}$ is the angle travelled towards west and $75^{\circ}$ is the angle travelled towards East.

$220$ is the distance travelled towards west in $22$ hours.

$176$ is the distance travelled towards East in $22$ hours.

Now we need to find $x$ and you can use Law of Cosines.

$$x^2=(220)^2+(176)^2-2(220)(176)\cos(118^{\circ})$$
Solve for $x$ and that will be your answer.

Comment: Quick question. How did you go about getting the 118 degrees?

Comment: @RTarson From the above diagram, take the dotted lines as reference. $13+90+(90-75)=13+90+15=118$

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate the angle between their paths
2. Calculate the length of each path
3. Form a triangle and use the law of cosines for the unknown side (the distance between them)